# openGL image quality (blured)

Tags: image, opengl, sdl

i use openGL to create an slideshow app. Unfortunatly the images rendered with openGL look **blured** compared to the gnome image viewer.

Here are the 2 Screenshots

(opengl) http://tinyurl.com/dxmnzpc

(image viewer) http://tinyurl.com/8hshv2a

and this is the base image:
http://tinyurl.com/97ho4rp

the image has the native size of my screen. (2560x1440)

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <unistd.h>

GLuint text = 0;

GLuint load_texture(const char* file) {
        SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load(file);

        GLuint texture;
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4);
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        SDL_PixelFormat *format = surface->format;
        printf("%d %d \n",surface->w,surface->h);
        if (format->Amask) {
                gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4,surface->w, surface->h, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
        } else {
                gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3,surface->w, surface->h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
        }
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

        return texture;
}

void display(void) {
        GLdouble offset_x = -1;
        GLdouble offset_y = -1;

        int p_viewport[4];
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, p_viewport); 

        GLfloat gl_width = p_viewport[2];//width(); // GL context size
        GLfloat gl_height = p_viewport[3];//height();

        glClearColor (0.0,2.0,0.0,1.0);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glLoadIdentity();
        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glTranslatef(0,0,0);

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, text);

        gl_width=2; gl_height=2;

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); //4
        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); //3
        glVertex2f(offset_x + gl_width, offset_y);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); // 2
        glVertex2f(offset_x + gl_width, offset_y + gl_height);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); // 1
        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y + gl_height);
        glEnd();

        glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        glutInit(&argc,argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE);

        glutGameModeString("2560x1440:24");
        glutEnterGameMode();       
        text = load_texture("/tmp/raspberry/out.jpg");

        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutMainLoop();
}
```

**UPDATED TRY**

```
void display(void)                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                          
        GLdouble texture_x = 0;                                                                                            
        GLdouble texture_y = 0;                                                                                            
        GLdouble texture_width = 0;                                                                                        
        GLdouble texture_height = 0;                                                                                       

        glViewport(0,0,width,height);                                                                                      

        glClearColor (0.0,2.0,0.0,1.0);                                                                                    
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);                                                                                     
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);                                                                                          

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                                                                                       
        glLoadIdentity();                                                                                                  
        glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);                                                                               

        //Do pixel calculatons                                                                                             
        texture_x = ((2.0*1-1) / (2*width));                                                                               
        texture_y = ((2.0*1-1) / (2*height));                                                                              
        texture_width=((2.0*width-1)/(2*width));                                                                           
        texture_height=((2.0*height-1)/(2*height));                                                                        

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                                                                                        
        glLoadIdentity();                                                                                                  
        glTranslatef(0,0,0);                                                                                               

        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );                                                                                         
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, text);                                                                               

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);                                                                                                 
        glTexCoord2f(texture_x, texture_height); //4                                                                       
        glVertex2f(0, 0);                                                                                                  

        glTexCoord2f(texture_width, texture_height); //3                                                                   
        glVertex2f(width, 0);                                                                                              

        glTexCoord2f(texture_width, texture_y); // 2                                                                       
        glVertex2f(width,height);                                                                                          

        glTexCoord2f(texture_y, texture_y); // 1                                                                           
        glVertex2f(0,height);                                                                                              
        glEnd();                                                                                                           

        glutSwapBuffers();                                                                                                 
}
```

Comment: The image links seem to be broken. Could you please upload the images here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is really the problem, but I think you don't need/want mipmaps here. Have you tried using [`glTexImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) instead of `gluBuild2DMipmaps` in combination with nearest neighbor filtering ([`glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN`/`MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml))?

Comment: Switching filtering to GL_NEAREST doesn't solve OP's problem. It may seem to work, but it actually doesn't. See my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

What you run into is a variation of the *fencepost problem*, that arises from how OpenGL deals with texture coordinates. OpenGL does not address a texture's pixels (texels), but uses the image data as support for a interpolation, that in fact covers a wider range than the images pixels. So the texture coordinates 0 and 1 don't hit the left-/bottom most and right-/top most pixels, but go a little further, in fact.

Let's say the texture is 8 pixels wide:

```
 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
 ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
0.0  |   |   |   |   |   |   |  1.0
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
0/8 1/8 2/8 3/8 4/8 5/8 6/8 7/8 8/8
```

The digits denote the texture's pixels, the bars the edges of the texture and in case of nearest filtering the border between pixels. You however want to hit the pixels' centers. So you're interested in the texture coordinates

(0/8 + 1/8)/2 = 1 / (2 * 8)

(1/8 + 2/8)/2 = 3 / (2 * 8)

...

(7/8 + 8/8)/2 = 15 / (2 * 8)

Or more generally for pixel i in a N wide texture the proper texture coordinate is

(2i + 1)/(2N)

However if you want to perfectly align your texture with the screen pixels, remember that what you specify as coordinates are not a quad's pixels, but edges, which, depending on projection may align with screen pixel edges, not centers, thus may require other texture coordinates.

Note that if you follow this, irregardless of your filtering mode and mipmaps your image will always look clear and crisp, because the interpolation hits exactly your sampling support, which is your input image. Switching to another filtering mode, like GL_NEAREST may look right at first look, but it's actually not correct, because it will alias your samples. *So don't do it.*

---

There are few other issues with your code as well, but they're not as a huge problem. First and foremost, you're choosing a rather arcane way to viewport dimensions. You're (probably without further thought) explout the fact that the default OpenGL viewport is the size of the window the context has been created with. You're using SDL, which has the side effect, that this approach won't bite you, as long as you stick with SDL-1. But switch to any other framework, that may create the context via a proxy drawable, and you're running into a problem.

The canonical way is usually to retrieve the window size from the windowing system (SDL in your case) and then *setting* the viewport at one of the first actions in the display function.

Another issue is your use of `gluBuildMipmaps`, because a) you don't want to use mipmaps and b) since OpenGL-2 you can upload texture images of arbitrary size (i.e. you're not limited to powers of 2 for the dimensions), which completely eliminates the need for gluBuildMipmaps. So don't use it. Just use glTexImage2D directly and switch to a non-mipmapping filtering mode.

#### Update due to question update

The way you calculate the texture coordinates still doesn't look right. It seems like you're starting to count at 1. Texture pixels are 0 base indexed, so…

This is how I'd do it:

Assuming the projection maps the viewport

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                                                                                       
    glLoadIdentity();                                                                                                  
    glOrtho(0, win_width, 0, win_height, -1, 1);   

    glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);
```

we calculate the texture coordinates as

```
    //Do pixel calculatons      
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, text);                                                                                           
    GLint tex_width, tex_height;
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH,  &tex_width);
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &tex_height);

    texture_s1 = 1. / (2*width);  // (2*0-1
    texture_t1 = 1. / (2*height);                        
    texture_s2 = (2.*(tex_width -1) + 1) / (2*width);
    texture_t2 = (2.*(tex_height-1) + 1) / (2*height);
```

Note that tex_width and tex_height give the *number* of pixels in each direction, but the coordinates are 0 based, so you've to subtract 1 from them for the texture coordinate mapping. Hence we also use a constant 1 in the numerator for the s1, t1 coordinates.

The rest looks okay, given the projection you choose

```
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );                                                                                         

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                                                                                                 
    glTexCoord2f(s1, t1); //4                                                                       
    glVertex2f(0, 0);                                                                                                  

    glTexCoord2f(s2, t1); //3                                                                   
    glVertex2f(tex_width, 0);                                                                                              

    glTexCoord2f(s2, t2); // 2                                                                       
    glVertex2f(tex_width,tex_height);                                                                                          

    glTexCoord2f(s1, t2); // 1                                                                           
    glVertex2f(0,tex_height);                                                                                              
    glEnd();
```

Comment: hmm ok: 1 changed gl_width=1+((2.0*2560-1)/(2*2560)); and hight and the offset to your formular. 
i also changed to GL_LINEAR
 glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);    

but directly compared to the gl_width = 2 ; offset_x = -1 the results with your complexe calculate look more blured (but the quality is very close)

Comment: @aatdark: Did you also take into account if your vertex positions are right? You're not setting a projection and your gl_width and gl_height variables do not really make sense in your code. I recommend setting the GL_PPROJECTION matrix to a glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1), and using GL_MODELVIEW to apply the offset by glTranslatef.

Comment: ok i posted an updated source above. Again it is blured a little bit. Filtering is GL_LINEAR. I want to show images that already have exactly the same resolution as the screen.

Comment: i used your code, but s1=0,t1=0,s2=1,t2=1 still looks better. Maybe
 glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
is the problem. Anyway, thx for your effort ;) At least i got rid of NEAREST ..